# How to cache certain resources during website development

Tags: css, wordpress, caching, google-chrome-devtools, development-environment

I'm developing a WordPress based site on a local installation (MAMP). I usually have cache disabled in Chrome Developer tools, but when I have slow internet it would be convenient to only reload certain files (css files of the theme) and cache other resources (font-awesome, google fonts, etc).

Is selective caching a feature of the Chrome Developer Tools? I only found the global disable cache option. If not do you have any other solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know for chrome, but you can use a custom .htaccess on your dev mamp folder :

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|jpg|jpeg|gif|css|js)$">
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

change the "ico|pdf|jpg|jpeg|gif|css|js" for matching the file extension you want to cache, and disable the caching feature of chrome.

hope it helps.

Comment: What does this do exactly? It looks very much what I want I think.

Comment: it say to your browser that all file with *.xx extension don't have to be redownloaded before 1 year ( you can adjust this value ).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not to use chrome's disable cache feature, rather use 
CDNs for the font-awesome and other google/jquery/bootstrap APIs. So they will be automatically cached in the browser. And do the versioning of js and css files that you work upon to avoid their cacheing. 
like `<script src = "/js/example.js?v=23242" ></script>`. So when ever you change any of these file, also change their version number. May be there are ways in wordpress to do this automatically.
Or you can use things like gulp/grunt to do versioning of js/css files.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. WordPress supports the version number for css and js files and I walways wondered what theyre good for. Makes sense now. But this would require me to change the version number upon each change, even if I go back and forth with changes. I dont feel like it fits into my workflow, but thank you anyways!

Comment: I am using a CDN for font awesome and google fonts, so I dont know about that one..